# searching for a record in mysql using query browser

Tags: mysql, jdbc

I have made a database in mysql using query browser to store passwords and username. I want to create a login page where user enters login details and on submit, it checks whether the username and password combination exists. how do i fire a query that searches the database for the record of that user?

Comment: What exactly is your question?  How to set up a page?  How to connect to a database?  How to query the database?  How to validate username/password?  Start developing - and come back with specific questions.  This site is not a code-generation service.

Comment: I apologize i forgot to upload the earlier code. I just wanted to know what query to fire

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Select * from yourTable where user_name ='user name here' and password = 'password here';
```